# Foreach set the value when button click on inside foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using JS knockout, see this example code:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: qcitems">
    <input data-bind="value: $root.itemnumber" class="form-control" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.getItemNumber" class="form-control btn-warning">
        Click Get Item Number
    </button>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: addQCitem, enable: qcitems().length < 3" class="btn btn-default">
    Add another item
</button>
```

In this I have an `itemnumber` textbox and `getItemNumber` button. I want to set a value when this button is clicked.

If possible I want to have `getItemNumber` spawn a popup window, to I will be able to get feed from API and set the value.

Comment: `A value` and `the value` are pretty vague. What value are you trying to set? What sort of content will the popup need to contain?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question but I guess this will help you,

**Edited View**

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.getItemNumber" class="form-control btn-warning" onclick="transferData('$root.getItemNumber');">Click Get Item Number</button>
```

here: the 'transferData' will send a string variable = *getItemNumber* to your Javascript

**Script**

```
function transferData(x) { $('#popWindow').value(x); }
```

and after passing it to the javascript you need to add the ID of your popWindow here **'#popWindow'**. 
this script will get your getItemNumber value and transfer that value to your popWindow value.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for the `onclick` handler  The `transferData` code would be better off being called from the `$root.getItemNumber` function.